# Running a quartz job in grails?

Tags: mysql, grails, timestamp, quartz-scheduler

I'm very new to Grails. I have a table like this :

```
+----+---------+----------------+----------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+--------+---------------------+
| id | version | card_exp_month | card_exp_year  | card_number | card_security_code | name_on_card | txn_id | date_created        |
+----+---------+----------------+----------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+--------+---------------------+
|  9 |       0 | ASdsadsd       | Asdsadsadasdas | Asdsa       |                    | batman       | asd    | 2012-08-13 19:38:22 |
+----+---------+----------------+----------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+--------+---------------------+
```

In mysql. I wish to run a Quartz job against this table, which will compare, `date_created` Time stamp with present time such that, if any field's there with timestamp less than 30 minutes should be deleted.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could define a Job implementing your logic ( in the execute() method, check (date_created - now) < 30 minutes or else delete the row in the database) and then trigger this job on a regular basis.

You can read the documentation http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook or have a look at the examples : http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/quartz/branches/quartz-2.2.x/examples/src/main/java/org/quartz/examples/example1/

Answer (score 0):

Check this example for grails quartz:

http://www.juancarlosfernandez.net/2012/02/como-crear-un-proceso-quartz-en-grails.html